Is it possible to create a measure that takes the status from a previous month into account?
I'm trying to come up with a measure to calculate the count of "Work Items ID's" in a certain state for a selected month. The issue is that, as long as the Work item stays in the same state, there is no data available (so whenever there is no data, the state from the latest available date needs to be taken into account).
In example below I want to calculate how many work items are in state 4 in month "2023-01"
For Item 12 it is clear, but for item 10 there is no value -> looking at previous known month we see that is was (and is) in state 4



Work Item ID
Month
State




10
2022-09
1


10
2022-12
4


10
2023-03
5


10
2023-12
2


12
2022-10
2


12
2023-01
4


12
2023-06
5



enter image description here
I came up with a solution in Excel - multiplying the 4 rows of data for item 10 with a "calender"
Step 1) all values in the calender > 2023-01 are out of scope
Step 2) all values for Date Recalc (=month) > are out of scope
Step 3) taking the max value of the remaining values from "Date Recalc" is 2022-12 -> This is the value in the original table which has the correct state
Result of the measure should be (when selecting 2023-01) 2 (as for count of work item id's in step 4)

what's the expected output? you want to display in a card with month selection? or you want to display the whole year?

Expected output is a measure that calculate the distinct count for all Work Item ID's that are considered to be in state = 4 when I selected "2023-01" in a dropdown menu

Try this:
Count of work items in selected state = CALCULATE(
    SUMX(
        VALUES('Work Items IDs'[Work Item ID]), 
        CALCULATE(IF(MAX('Work Items IDs'[State]) = SELECTEDVALUE('States'[State]), 1, 0))
    ),
    'Work Items IDs'[Month] <= SELECTEDVALUE('Months'[Month])
)

Note that there should not be any active relationship between table 'Work Items IDs' and any of 'States' or 'Months'
